# How to remove single and double char tokens using quanteda::tokens_select()

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to remove single and double char tokens.

here is an example:

`toks <- tokens(c("This is a sentence. This is a second sentence."), remove_punct = TRUE)`

`toks <- tokens_select(toks, min_nchar=1L, max_nchar=2L, selection = "remove")`

`toks`

Results:

> tokens from 1 document.
>   text1 :
>
> [1] "is" "a"  "is" "a"

I expect to get the tokens that do not meet the criteria, instead of the ones that meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the selection argument is ignored.

This gives the results I wanted.

`toks <- tokens_select(toks, min_nchar=3L, max_nchar=79L)`

Answer (score 6):

```
library(quanteda)

toks <- tokens(c("This is a sentence. This is a second sentence."), remove_punct = TRUE)
tokens_select(toks, min_nchar=3L)
```

Comment: These also work:
`tokens_remove(toks, c("?", "??"))`
`tokens_keep(toks, min_nchar = 3)`

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the given sentence into tokens. You can do the following:

```
library(quanteda)

# convert to tokens
tokens <- unlist(tokens(sent, remove_punct = T), use.names=F)

# to remove tokens with <= 2 characters
Filter(function(x) nchar(x) > 2, tokens)

[1] "This"     "sentence" "This"     "second"   "sentence"
```